# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ds' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, geolocation, angular9

I am using angular to create a app which asks for the location of user using browser.
Below is my ts file code snippet.

this is constructor in ts file.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private ds: DataService) { }
```

---

this is the function

```
showposition(position) {
var lati = position.coords.latitude;
var long = position.coords.longitude;
console.log(lati, long);

this.ds.storeLocation({
  // email:this.email,
  longitude: long,
  lattitude: lati,
})
  .subscribe((response) => {
    if (response.status == "ok") {
      alert('Your location successfuly stored');
    }
    else {
      alert("error in saving location");
    }
  })
```

}

the console.log() is printing lattitude and longitude on console screen but **error is raising at  this.ds.storeLocation**.

Also i have written all necessary code in my data.service.ts file also -

```
storeLocation(d):any{
return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/corona-tracker', d);
 }
```

Comment: How is `showposition()` function called? I assume it's a callback?

Comment: @MichaelD we ourself dont have to call it,yes its a callback.

Comment: Could you please show how it's called?

Comment: @PardeepJain But i have already done this in my constructor

Comment: @MichaelD                    getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      console.log("success");
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showposition);
    }
    else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, the function `showposition()` is a callback. In order to preserve the meaning of `this` keyword in a callback, you could either  use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function with `this` keyword, or use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) notation. Try the following

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showposition.bind(this));
```

Comment: yes it solved that error though a new error is raised but i can solve that.

Comment: something related to my databse but then i solved it

Answer (score 0):

You should define arrow function for `showposition` otherwise you should bind `this` for the normal function expression.

Comment: i have binded this for normal function

Comment: there was some other type of error which i sorted out

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the latest code after all the changes you have made

Comment: here is my final code                                                            
    `getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      console.log("success");
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((p)=>{this.showposition(p)});    
    }
    else {
          console.log("error");
        }
  }`